Shopify Hydrogen useLoadScript() loads, but code is not working
I'm using flowbite in my Shopify Hydrogen build.
This works:
export default function App() {
  const nonce = useNonce();
  /** @type {LoaderReturnData} */
  const data = useLoaderData();
  const location = useLocation();
  const isHomePage = location.pathname === '/';
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body className="font-rcc">
      <Layout isHomePage={isHomePage} {...data}>
          <Outlet />
        </Layout>
        <ScrollRestoration nonce={nonce} />
        <Scripts nonce={nonce} />
        <LiveReload nonce={nonce} />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.js" defer></script>
        
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

but this does not. I'm using the proper useLoadScript in this case, and I do see in the DOM
export default function App() {
  const nonce = useNonce();
  /** @type {LoaderReturnData} */
  const data = useLoaderData();
  const location = useLocation();
  const isHomePage = location.pathname === '/';
  const scriptStatus = useLoadScript('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/2.3.0/flowbite.min.js');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (scriptStatus === 'done') {
      // do something
    }
  }, [scriptStatus]);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body className="font-rcc">
      <Layout isHomePage={isHomePage} {...data}>
          <Outlet />
        </Layout>
        <ScrollRestoration nonce={nonce} />
        <Scripts nonce={nonce} />
        <LiveReload nonce={nonce} />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

When I view inspector, I see it in the DOM and there is an 'event' tag next to it. Clicking that, I see 'error' and 'load'
error:
() => {
  reject(false);
}

load:
() => {
  resolve(true);
}

It seems like a timing thing? Struggling on this one!
